# Merge values from values in a map with each other based on key

Tags: java, arrays, merge, hashmap, maps

I am stuck since 2 hours(I am dumb) with this strange problem.

I have a map with the values like `<String,Set>`

- A = 1,2,3
- B = 4,5
- C = 6

The output I am looking is

- A=1&B=4&C=6
- A=1&B=5&C=6
- A=2&B=4&C=6
- A=2&B=5&C=6
- A=3&B=4&C=6
- A=3&B=5&C=6

What I have done so far :-

- Iterate over the map based on the first key and store values in an array
- Iterate over the second key, but I am not sure how I can merge the values from the first result to this one.
- Forget the third and subsequent keys.

This may sound like a very dumb question but I am not able to figure this out. I tried to avoid the scenario to reach here but I could not change!!

Please help.

Note:- I used multiset too but it accepted duplicate values for the values, so had to use a set.Hence ended up with a `map<String,Set>`.

Comment: Do you always have those three exact keys?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman - No. The keys change. they are not constant.

Comment: Are external libraries allowed?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman - Nope. :(

Comment: What should the output be? Print those combination on screen? Put in into another data structure (which one?)

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax - Add them in an arrayList. I am looking for a way to insert the output I have mentioned in an arrayList.

Comment: Google Gauava might be able to help

Comment: And the arraylist contains maps, right?

Comment: @ Matthias J. Sax - What I have is a map. I want the output in an arraylist of strings concatenating different values in the map.

Comment: Recursion should be the right approach.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax No need for recursion.

Comment: Well. Every recursive algorithm can be expresses iteratively, too. So recursion is never "needed". However, it seems to be a native way to do it recursively. Anyway. Your answers presents is a nice solution :)

Comment: Ok, whats recursion here? @Andreas @ Matthias J. Sax

Comment: @LearningEveryday [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) means a method that calls itself. Call can be indirect, e.g. `a()` calls `b()` calls `a()`.

Comment: @Andreas - I tried that and ended up in an infinite loop. Never again. Struggle is real.

Comment: @LearningEveryday As your names says, you're learning every day, and *one day* you'll learn to do recursion correctly. :-)

Comment: @Andreas I am 27 and these kind of things bug me. Again thank you. Here, have a cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code can handle any size of the Map, *except empty*, and any size of each Set, *except empty*. An empty Map/Set will throw an error.

Of course, extending the code to handle *empty* should be fairly simple, once you define the expected output.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("A", new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")));
map.put("B", new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList("4", "5")));
map.put("C", new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList("6")));

List<String> result = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = (result == null ? "" : "&") + entry.getKey() + "=";
    Set<String> values = entry.getValue();
    if (values.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty set not supported");
    List<String> crossJoin = new ArrayList<>((result == null ? 1 : result.size()) * values.size());
    if (result == null)
        for (String value : values)
            crossJoin.add(key + value);
    else
        for (String left : result)
            for (String value : values)
                crossJoin.add(left + key + value);
    result = crossJoin;
}
if (result == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty map not supported");
for (String value : result)
    System.out.println(value);
```

*Output*

```
A=1&B=4&C=6
A=1&B=5&C=6
A=2&B=4&C=6
A=2&B=5&C=6
A=3&B=4&C=6
A=3&B=5&C=6
```

Comment: This works.I kind of was stuck between for inside a for was not able to figure out how to proceed. And the map keys and values cannot be null or blank. Also I have another question as to is there a way to make sure we have unique values in the case of a multiset values?

Comment: Since input is Map and Set, all values are unique, unless you mean "A=1&B=1" is invalid.

Comment: In case you have more than three list in your map, you can join two lists at once, all the way to the end.

Comment: @Will but I may lose the data of the key. I need both.

Comment: I revisited the same problem after years and solved this using javascript as well!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer which is easier to read and will be much more maintainable if your code is sticking around for a while and you might want to change your formatting or handling of empty cases. It naturally handles cases with an empty map and with keys which have no set of allowed values.

I have assumed order is unimportant to you, but you can replace the sets with lists to get a more predictable/consistent order.

```
/**
 * A nested pair class to handle the mappings like A:1.
 */
private static class Pair{
    public Pair(String k,String v){
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    String k;
    String v;

    public String toString(){
        return k+"="+v;
    }
}

/**
 * Given a set like 
 * {{A:"s1",B:"s4","C:s5"}
 * {A:"s1",B:"s4","C:s6"}
 * {A:"s2",B:"s4","C:s5"}
 * {A:"s2",B:"s4","C:s6"}
 * {A:"s3",B:"s4","C:s5"}
 * {A:"s3",B:"s4","C:s6"}}
 * 
 * Converts the contents to string like:
 * A=s1&B=s4&C=s5
 * A=s1&B=s4&C=s6
 * A=s2&B=s4&C=s5
 * A=s2&B=s4&C=s6
 * A=s3&B=s4&C=s5
 * A=s3&B=s4&C=s6
 * @param pairCombinations
 * @return
 */
public static String format(Set<Set<Pair>> pairCombinations){
    String result = "";
    for(Set<Pair> pairSet : pairCombinations){
        result += formatPairSet(pairSet)+"\n";
    }

    return result;
}

private static String formatPairSet(Set<Pair> pairSet) {
    String result = "";
    boolean isFirst = true;
    for(Pair pair : pairSet){
        result+= (isFirst? "" : "&");
        result += pair.k+"="+pair.v;
        isFirst = false;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Given a map of the form:
 * A:{"s1","s2","s3"}
 * B:{"s4"}
 * C:{"s5","s6"}
 * 
 * Will return all possible combinations of pairs in 
 * the map as:
 * {{A:"s1",B:"s4","C:s5"}
 * {A:"s1",B:"s4","C:s6"}
 * {A:"s2",B:"s4","C:s5"}
 * {A:"s2",B:"s4","C:s6"}
 * {A:"s3",B:"s4","C:s5"}
 * {A:"s3",B:"s4","C:s6"}}
 * @param map
 * @return
 */
public static Set<Set<Pair>> getCombinations(Map<String,Set<String>> map){

    Set<Set<Pair>> combinations = new HashSet<Set<Pair>>();
    if(map.entrySet().isEmpty()){
        return combinations;
    }
    combinations.add(new HashSet<Pair>());

    Set<Pair> pairsForKey = null;
    for(Entry<String,Set<String>> mapEntry : map.entrySet()){
        //Ex: {C:"s5",C:"s6"}
        pairsForKey = getPairs(mapEntry);

        //Ex: {{A:s1,B:s4},{A:s2,B:s4},{A:s3,B:s4}}
        combinations = join(combinations,pairsForKey);
    }

    return combinations;
}

private static Set<Pair> getPairs(Entry<String, Set<String>> kWithValidVs) {
    Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<Pair>();
    for(String v : kWithValidVs.getValue()){
        pairs.add(new Pair(kWithValidVs.getKey(),v));
    }
    return pairs;
}

/**
 * Given a set of combinations like:
 * {{A:s1,B:s4},{A:s2,B:s4},{A:s3,B:s4}} and a set to join with it like {C:s5,C:s6},
 * will join the set to the existing combinations like:
 * {{A:s1,B:s4,C:s5},{A:s2,B:s4,C:s5},{A:s3,B:s4,C:s5},{A:s1,B:s4,C:s6},{A:s2,B:s4,A:s6},{A:s3,B:s4,C:s6}}
 * @param combinations
 * @param set
 * @return
 */
private static Set<Set<Pair>> join(Set<Set<Pair>> combinations,
        Set<Pair> set) {
    Set<Set<Pair>> join = new HashSet<Set<Pair>>();

    //comment this 'if' if you want keys with empty lists to eliminate all combos.
    if(set.isEmpty()){
        return combinations;
    }

    for(Set<Pair> combo : combinations){
        for(Pair pair : set){
            Set<Pair> newCombo = new HashSet<Pair>();
            newCombo.addAll(combo);
            newCombo.add(pair);
            join.add(newCombo);
        }
    }
    return join;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String,Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
    Set<String> aVals = new HashSet<String>();
    aVals.add("1");
    aVals.add("2");
    aVals.add("3");

    Set<String> bVals = new HashSet<String>();
    bVals.add("4");

    Set<String> cVals = new HashSet<String>();
    cVals.add("5");
    cVals.add("6");

    map.put("A", aVals);
    map.put("B", bVals);
    map.put("C", cVals);

    Set<Set<Pair>> combinations =getCombinations(map);
    String printableResult = format(combinations);
    System.out.print(printableResult);
}
```

Output:

```
A=2&B=4&C=6
A=2&B=4&C=5
A=1&B=4&C=6
B=4&C=5&A=3
B=4&A=3&C=6
A=1&B=4&C=5
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will definitely keep this mind.